# How do I use compare parameter for sort() with a template and custom data structure

Tags: c++, templates, sorting, stl

I would like to create a compare function object that will help me sort a vector of a custom data structure. I am struggling to work out where exactly it should be implemented and any additional code required since I am using a template at the same time. Most of the code below can be ignored. It is included for completeness but the compare function object is used at the very end of `printSummary()`. In a nutshell, how do I implement the compare function object?

```
#include<map>
#include<vector>
//#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Record{
   public:
   T item;
   int total;
};

   template<class T>
   bool compare(const Record<T> & a, const Record<T> & b){ //should a come before b?
      if(a.total > b.total)
         return true;
      if(a.total < b.total)
         return false;
      if(a.total == b.total){
         if(a.item < b.item)
            return true; 
         else
            return false;
      }
   }

template <class T>
class Counter{
   public:
      map<T, int> m;

   void printSummary(){

      typename map<T, int>::const_iterator itr; 
      vector< Record<T> > printlist;
      Record<T> temp;
      int i = 0;

      for( itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); ++itr ){
         temp.item = (*itr).first;
         temp.total = (*itr).second;
         printlist.push_back(temp);
         i++;
      }

      sort(printlist.begin(), printlist.end(), compare);

      //output sorted printlist contents
   }

};
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Where should I put/how should I code `compare()` so it can be accessed by `sort()`

Comment: It's OK to put it there. Just specify an instantiation when passing it to `sort()`. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your call to `sort()`, you are specifying the name of a function *template* **without instantiating it**:

```
sort(printlist.begin(), printlist.end(), compare);
//                                       ^^^^^^^
```

The bare name of a function template represents a **whole overload set** for the compiler (where the set includes all the possible specializations of that template).

To disambiguate, you need to instantiate `compare<>()` in order to provide the address of *one* function:

```
sort(printlist.begin(), printlist.end(), compare<T>);
//                                              ^^^
```

Alternatively, you can make `compare` a *functor*:

```
struct compare
{
   template<class T>
   bool operator () (const Record<T> & a, const Record<T> & b)
   {
      // should a come before b?
      if(a.total > b.total)
         return true;
      if(a.total < b.total)
         return false;
      if(a.total == b.total){
         if(a.item < b.item)
            return true; 
         else
            return false;
      }
   }
};
```

Then, you can pass it to `sort()` this way, without template instantiation (but you need to create an instance of your functor, although a temporary is fine, as shown below):

```
sort(printlist.begin(), printlist.end(), compare());
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can the same point can be made for instantiating a `Record` object? I needed to specify `Record<T>` so the compiler knows to use `template<class T>` (which I did do in the example) as opposed to some other template say `template<class U>`

Comment: @user1905552: I think I do not understand your question, can you rephrase?

Comment: Can I try a different question. If I use the first solution you mention, could I have `compare<U>` in `sort()`? Could I then write a new compare function object under `template<class U>` potentially containing different logic?

Comment: @user1905552: I still don't understand. If you are just replacing `T` by `U`, that's a no-change. `T` and `U` are only symbolic names for the type parameter of the `Counter` template

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine so far, you must only qualify `compare` with the type `T`

```
sort(printlist.begin(), printlist.end(), compare<T>);
```

In your compare function, you can omit

```
if(a.total == b.total){
```

because at that point, it is always equal. You can reduce this to just

```
if (a.total > b.total)
    return true;

if (a.total < b.total)
    return false;

return a.item < b.item;
```